# Create new instance of Resource per request in DropWizard

Tags: rest, jboss, resources, instance, dropwizard

I am trying to refactor my REST API so we can use DropWizard.

The problem I am running into is with thread safety.   According to the DropWizard's Getting Started - "Resource classes are used by multiple threads concurrently. In general, we recommend that resources be stateless/immutable, but it’s important to keep the context in mind."

It would require a major overhaul to refactor my codebase - I am curious if there is a way to configure DropWizard so that each request creates a new instance of my resource?

In my run() method, I have code that looks like:

```
public void run(AppConfig configuration, Environment environment)
{
    final MyResource myResource = new MyResource();
    environment.jersey().register(myResource);
}
```

Is it possible to configure DropWizard so that a new instance of MyResource is created per request?   Currently I am using JBOSS, and that is the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to register the resource like this:

```java
public void run(AppConfig configuration, Environment environment) {
  environment.jersey().register(MyResource.class);
}
```

and a new instance will be created per request.

Comment: New instance of MyResource ?

Comment: @siddhusingh I know it might be too late, but yes.